# Kinesis for mobile client

Tags: mobile, amazon-kinesis

I'm evaluating Kinesis as a logging front end for mobile client, and all data processing workers run behind Kinesis. Regarding to authentication, what's the proper way to implement? Basically, what the application can do are,

1. fix auth info in app and provide user id in request, send it to server side with AWS mobile client, which also allows bad guy to submit arbitrary fake request
2. implement a server in between the mobile client and kinesis, and apply our own auth check before sending to Kinesis
3. or is there any better practice I've missed?

Comment: Cognito - http://aws.amazon.com/cognito

Comment: I think mobile client publishing to Kinesis (or any other backend) is not a great idea in general, you are making your frontend aware of backend dependencies, what happens if you introduce something other than Kinesis.   However the concern of bad guy submitting arbitrary fake request is still not possible, unless you have auth tokens exposed in your application. Is that what you are worried about?

Comment: actually I hold similar understanding as yours now. in our project we implemented a front-end server to forward the log to kinesis. you may want to reply as an answer and easier for me to set it as accepted answer.

Comment: I'd argue that using the mobile client to push to Kinesis is an ideal solution for small teams.  The cost and time savings of having a reliable event queue on your mobile client that automatically handles loss of network and other exceptions, and utilizing the Kinesis API that is built to automatically scale as throughput increases, outweigh the advantage of being able to remove Kinesis from your tech stack w/o re-deploying your apps.  This is no different than relying on Mixpanel or Fabric for analytics.